# mongoose-crate-localfs: throws error : "Attachment has no path property"

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to upload many files to the mongoDb, I'm using mongoose-crate-localfs for doing that, I implemented the schema as in the documentation, but still when I try to attach the file to my attachment, it throws that error : Attachment has no path property.
So here is the front end : I have a form with enctype= multipart/form-data :

```
<form   class="fileUpload col s12 uploadForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="col s12 containerUpload0">
        <div class="file-field input-field col s8 uploadInput0">
            <div class="file-path-wrapper col s4">
                <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload one or more files">
            </div>
            <div class="btn btn1">
                <span>Choose your file</span>
                <input type="file" id="fileToUpload0" name="fileUploaded">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none">
            <input type="text" name="filePath" id="filePath">
        </div>
 </div>
```

This is the upload javascript file :upload.js

```
$(".uploadForm").on("submit", function(event) { $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            url: "/users/123458/upload/files" ,
            beforeSubmit: function() {

            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                $(".determinate").css("width", percentComplete+ "%")
                $('.percentage').text(percentComplete +"%")
                //$(".filesDetails").append('<p id="progress-status">' + percentComplete +' %</p>')
            },
            success: function( response) {
                if (response ==="success") {
                    $(".uploader").hide();
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.status);
            },
            resetForm:true
        })
    }
    return false;})
```

And this is the server.js code : 
(the uploadD.array is the multer variable with a disk storage and not inMemory storage

```
app.post("/users/:useriD/upload/files", uploadD.array('fileUploaded',12) , function (req, res) {
    if (sessionUser._id !== req.params.useriD) {
        res.render("ErrorForbidden")
    } else {
        db.Temp.create( {
            _user: sessionUser._id
        }, function (error, newTempF) {
            if (error) {
                res.send("error")
            } else {
                newTempF.attach("attachments", req.files[0].path , (err) => {
                    if (err)  {
                        return res.send(err)
                    } else {
                        newTempF.save((err) => {
                            if (err) {
                                return res.send(err)
                            } else {
                                console.log("SUCCES")
                            return res.send('success')      
                            }
                        })
                    }

                })
            }
        })
        // db.Temp.create
    }
})
```

So for now, i'm just trying to upload only one file, but everytime I do that it throws that error, but when I console.log (req.files[0].path), it shows me the correct file path.
This is the file schema :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
crate = require('mongoose-crate'),
LocalFS = require('mongoose-crate-localfs'),
path = require('path'),
user = require("./users.js");
var tempSchema = new Schema({
_user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"
}})
tempSchema.plugin(crate, {storage: new LocalFS({
  directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop', //the directory of the local upload
  path: function(attachment) { // where the file is stored in the bucket 
  return 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\' + attachment.filename
} }),
fields: {
  attachments: {
    array: true,
    path: String}}}) ;
var Temp =  mongoose.model('Temp', tempSchema); 
module.exports = Temp`;
```

And here is how req.files looks like in the server : 
[image]

Can anyone help me with this?